Factorial for Natural Number Object
It is Awodey Exercise 17 in Chapter 9. It asks to define factorial as an arrow $N \to N$ for a natural number object.
Awodey page 246 and 247 defines how to add a natural number by recursion. That is, it shows how to define $x\mapsto x +a$ for a fixed $a$. I think I know how to define addition and multiplication as maps $N \times N \to N$ as transposes of maps from $N$. However, the next step gives exponential instead of factorial. I think I would need to define the predecessor function before defining factorial. Is the usage of primitive recursion theorem (2.3 in
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object ) necessary. May I please ask how to do it?

The factorial function is defined by the following recursive equations:
$$
\begin{align}
0! &= 1 \\
(n + 1)! &= n! (n + 1)
\end{align}
$$
Because the second equation references the "current value" $n + 1$, this isn't of the form $n! = f^n(a)$ for any $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}, a : \mathbb{N}$; we have to somehow provide the value $n$ to the recursor.
One way to do this is to pair the value with the result: using $N \times N$ as the carrier for our algebra, take $a : 1 \to N \times N = \langle 0, s \circ 0 \rangle$, $f : N \times N \to N \times N = \langle s \circ \pi_1, m \circ \langle \pi_2, s \circ \pi_1 \rangle \rangle$, where $m : N \times N \to N$ is multiplication. This yields a map $u : N \to N \times N$, and we can define the factorial as $\pi_2 \circ u$.
